# How to find the index of the maximum absolute of the first time in a list of tuples?

Tags: python, sorting, max, tuples, absolute

Given a list of tuples:

```
[(-8.33958, -84.01769099999999), (-7.96129, -84.37399199999999), (-8.33958, -83.84126699999999), (-7.96129, -84.19756499999998), (-7.24097, -85.581651), (-6.86267, -85.937952), (-7.24097, -85.405227), (-6.86267, -85.76152499999999), (-9.4382, -83.473767), (-9.4382, -83.473767), (-8.35625, -85.11197399999999), (-9.0599, -83.83006499999999), (-9.0599, -83.83006499999999), (-7.97795, -85.46824499999998), (-8.35625, -84.93524699999999), (-7.97795, -85.29151799999998), (-8.33958, -85.03772699999999), (-8.00311, -88.17046199999997), (-5.88285, -86.59070369999999), (-6.86267, -88.655385), (-9.37174, -86.88101999999999), (-7.34506, -88.24291199999999), (-8.22317, -87.13259099999999), (-7.72054, -86.124309), (-8.35625, -86.131707), (-8.35625, -86.131707), (-7.03703, -88.90182), (-8.51394, -86.422992), (-8.51394, -85.83968999999999), (-9.61255, -85.510092), (-9.89311, -84.10327799999999), (-7.96129, -87.540312), (-9.13791, -86.022645)]
```

The aim is to find the index of the highest value of the first item in the tuple. With the example input above the output the index of the tuple `(-9.89311, -84.10327799999999)`

I have been doing it as such (but it doesn't return the right output):

```
x = [(-8.33958, -84.01769099999999), (-7.96129, -84.37399199999999), (-8.33958, -83.84126699999999), (-7.96129, -84.19756499999998), (-7.24097, -85.581651), (-6.86267, -85.937952), (-7.24097, -85.405227), (-6.86267, -85.76152499999999), (-9.4382, -83.473767), (-9.4382, -83.473767), (-8.35625, -85.11197399999999), (-9.0599, -83.83006499999999), (-9.0599, -83.83006499999999), (-7.97795, -85.46824499999998), (-8.35625, -84.93524699999999), (-7.97795, -85.29151799999998), (-8.33958, -85.03772699999999), (-8.00311, -88.17046199999997), (-5.88285, -86.59070369999999), (-6.86267, -88.655385), (-9.37174, -86.88101999999999), (-7.34506, -88.24291199999999), (-8.22317, -87.13259099999999), (-7.72054, -86.124309), (-8.35625, -86.131707), (-8.35625, -86.131707), (-7.03703, -88.90182), (-8.51394, -86.422992), (-8.51394, -85.83968999999999), (-9.61255, -85.510092), (-9.89311, -84.10327799999999), (-7.96129, -87.540312), (-9.13791, -86.022645)]


index_of_max_abs_j = -1
for i, (j,k) in enumerate(x):
    if j*j > index_of_max_abs_j:
        index_of_max_abs_j = i
print index_of_max_abs_j
```

The code returns the index of `max(j*j)` but is that right? Is it different from trying to find `max(|j|)`?

**But is there another way of achieving the same output?** Maybe with `sorted` and `reverse` and `key` with some `math.abs`? Is the alternative with `sorted`, `reverse` and/or `key` more efficient?

If there's any item in the list of tuples that has the same value, return the first index of the first instance of the maximum absolute value.

Comment: Your code compares `j*j` to the *index*.  Can that be right?

Comment: Yes, because j*j will give the highest square. The ranking should be the same as doing `math.abs()`. Right?

Comment: Oh it's different! Any idea why is the ranking is from `math.fabs()` different to `j*j`??

Comment: Do you need the list to stay in the same order? Or would sorting it work?

Comment: I need the index so sorting might require some tricks to get the index back or creating a new sorted list which is surely less memory efficient.

Comment: Are you certain that 32 is the desired output?  I get index 30, not index 32.  `d.index(sorted(d, key = lambda x: x[0]**2, reverse = True)[0])`

Comment: I still don't understand why you're comparing a *value* to an *index*, or why the maximum isn't at 30 with (-9.89311, -84.10327799999999).

Comment: Sorry my code didn't get the right number.

Comment: `a.index(max(a, key=lambda x: abs(x[0])))` outputs 30 as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're comparing the value of the first element of the tuple to the index, but this gets you the index of the tuple with the highest absolute value for the first element.

```
max_index = -1
max_value = 0
for i, z in enumerate(x):
    value = abs(z[0])
    if value > max_value:
        max_index = i
        max_value = value

print(x[max_index])
```

Or as a less readable one-liner,

```
print(x.index(max(x, key=lambda y:abs(y[0]))))
```

Comment: Short question, does `sorted(x, key=lambda y:abs(y[0]), reverse=True)` gives me a sorted list from `max(abs(y[0]))` first?

Comment: @alvas Yup. That's what `sorted` does.

Comment: When I do an assert, seems like sorted() didn't keep the order of the list when there's a tie.

Comment: @alvas It should (and it does on my machine). That's a different question, though.

Comment: That last one looks brilliant, but gives me this when I run it:  `ValueError: 9.89311 is not in list`  I like the attempt, though.

Comment: @Riccati Oops, yeah, I didn't test it. I'll remove it. :P

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative, offered without comment on efficiency:

```
y = [abs(item[0]) for item in x]
m = max(y)
print(y.index(m))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print(max((abs(value[0]),index) for (index,value) in enumerate(values))[1]
```

would give the index of the last element having the max element in one pass
with native function so should be the fastest way

If you really want to have the first of max elements you can do

```
print(-max((abs(value[0]),-index) for (index,value) in enumerate(values))[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in 2 steps get the max based on first key in step 1, then get index with the element

```
>>> max_value = sorted(x, key=lambda y: y[0])[0]

>>> x.index(max_value)

30
```